# Python 3.4 Operations on lists or tuples in test files

Tags: python

My problem to solve is:

> Open a .txt file, which contains pairs of integers in any form, IE
>
> ```
> 2,4
> 10,24
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> (2,4)
> (10,24)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> [(2,4),(10,24)]
> ```
>
> The assignment is to caluculate the product of all pairs and add them together. So for the test list that would be `(2*4)+(10*24)`.

I don't really know where to start, what is the most efficient way to put the pairs in the text file? Separated by space, commas, put it as nested lists?

I have tried zipping, creating lists, etc.

```
with open("txtfile.txt","r") as f:
for line in f:
    (list(line.split()))
```

returns

```
['2,4']
['10,24']
```

which is one of the more organized results without very excessive `''` notations.

How do I get the elements inside the list to be represented as separate integers instead of a string? How would I then go from there? Is a loop something that can solve the problem?

This is homework.

Comment: It seems that the pairs are all comma separated.  If I'm correct, by repeated use of `split` and `strip` ... read the docs for `strip`, it does more than most people's assumptions

Answer (score 0):

You dont need use `list` ,First you need to split your lines with `,` then use `map` and `int` function to get a int list for each digit and use `sum` function to add the multiple of items , also in this case i use [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__mul__):

```
from operator import mul
with open("txtfile.txt","r") as f :
    print  sum(mul(*map(int,line.split(','))) for line in f)

248
```

txtfile.txt :

```
2,4
10,24
```

Answer (score 0):

No error checking, quite *brute force* but it works, as in "when I tried, I got the right output..."

```
>>> a = '''2,4
10,24                                                 
(2,4)                                                
(10,24)
[(2,4),(10,24)]'''
>>> for l in a.split('\n'):
...    el = [int(e.strip('[]()')) for e in  l.split(',')]
...    print sum([i*j for i,j in zip(el[::2],el[1::2])])
8
240
8
240
248
>>>
```

How does it work?

1. the *element list* `el` is prepared in the 2nd line, first I split on commas every line of (simulated) input, then I stripped out all that unprofitable syntax and turned the result into integers
2. in the next line of code, for each line of input I pack together in couples (using the builtin `zip`) the odd and the even elements of the current list of integers, I unpack the couples into variables `i` and `j`, take their product and this sequence of products is feed into the builtin `sum` function, whose result I eventually print.

#### The *unavoidable* one-liner

```
>>> [sum(j*k for j,k in zip(i[::2],i[1::2])) for i in  [[int(e.strip('[]()')) for e in l] for l in [l.split(',') for l in a.split('\n')]]]
[8, 240, 8, 240, 248]
>>>
```

much complication is due to the necessity of keeping lines apart.